# Moving / cloning folder swift

Tags: file, swift, directory

I'm trying to copy and rename a folder in Swift. I went about this by saving all of the original folder's contents to a new address. However, it seems to be creating .exe files instead of folders. Any ideas how I can fix the below code?

```
func moveAssets () {
        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let enumerator:NSDirectoryEnumerator = fileManager.enumeratorAtPath(folderName)!

        while let element = enumerator.nextObject() as? String {
            if (element != "main.js") {
                var dataPath = documentsFolder.stringByAppendingPathComponent(timeStamp)
                var tPath = folderName.stringByAppendingPathComponent(element)
                fileManager.copyItemAtPath(tPath, toPath: dataPath, error: nil)
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Files_in_Swift_on_iOS_8):

```
var error: NSError?

if filemgr.moveItemAtPath(filepath1, toPath: filepath2, error: &error) {
    println("Move successful")
} else {
    println("Moved failed with error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
}
```

I will have to manually delete the .js file though